# Where can I get the cabarc utility?

Tags: download, installation, cab

I'm trying to compile a program which uses `cabarc.exe`, but I don't have `cabarc.exe`. The problem is that the [Microsoft Cabinet SDK](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310618) is no longer available so I can't get it from there either.

Where can I get this file?

P.S. I'm looking for a download from a trusted source such as microsoft.com

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It [appears](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/356332/vs2008-team-edition-does-not-contain-cabarc-utility) that the `cabarc.exe` utility has been replaced with `makecab.exe`, which comes with Windows <sup>[[source]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367841(VS.85).aspx#1)</sup>.

It should be located in:

- C:\WINDOWS\system32

The `cabarc` documentation can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310618).

The `makecab` documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb267310.aspx).

Comment: Note that makecab produces a lot of extra artifacts that cabarc does not, such as a disk1/ directory, a setup.inf and a setup.rpt file.

Comment: If you want to avoid getting the extra directories and setup files, you must add directives
    
    .Set DiskDirectoryTemplate=.
    .Set InfFileName=NUL
    .Set RptFileName=NUL
    
in the `.ddf` file.

Comment: It also works to set the directive variables on the `makecab` command line, e.g. `makecab /D DiskDirectoryTemplate=. /D InfFileName=NUL /D RptFileName=NUL`

Comment: `makecab` has a different command line syntax, so it won't work as a drop-in replacement. [`cabarc` command line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx#com_line_usage), [`makecab` command line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx#syntax).

Answer (score 17):

`cabarc.exe` is available as a part of the [Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools](http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/3/8/d38066aa-4e37-4ae8-bce3-a4ce662b2024/WindowsXP-KB838079-SupportTools-ENU.exe).

You can extract only this utility using commands like these (if you don't run XP):

```
WindowsXP-KB838079-SupportTools-ENU.exe /C /T:%TEMP%
extract /E %TEMP%\support.cab cabarc.exe
```

Comment: On Windows 7 64bit I wasn't able to execute the extract portion, so after extracting support.cab I just "unzipped" it with WinRAR and found cabarc.exe

Comment: If you have [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) installed, you can extract them directly:
`7z e WindowsXP-KB838079-SupportTools-ENU.exe support.cab` and then 
`7z e support.cab cabarc.exe`

Comment: If you use the GUI version of 7-zip, you can also open the *.exe by right clicking and selecting "Open Inside", then double click into the "support.cab" and voila.

Comment: [Windows Server 2003 Support Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15326) also contains cabarc.exe (version 5.2.3790.0)

Answer (score 3):

You can download the CabSDK from here:

[Download the Microsoft Cabinet SDK version 4.71.410.0](http://www.pixelsplasher.com/_downloads/software/Microsoft-Cabinet-SDK/)

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 7 (and possibly Vista) instead of extract you use expand. The syntax is slightly different, but see below for the one that worked for me. Replace %TEMP% in the second command with wherever you want the cabarc.exe file to end up.

`WindowsXP-KB838079-SupportTools-ENU.exe /C /T:%TEMP%`

`expand %TEMP%\support.cab -F:cabarc.exe %TEMP%`

Answer (score 2):

You can find cabarc.exe in the [Internet Explorer Administration Kit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/bb219517.aspx).

Strangely though, IEAK 11 has cabarc.exe version 5.0.2147.1, while IEAK 10 has version 6.2.9200.16521.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 use the Windows ADK

Download and install the Windows ADK from [this website](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=232339).

for the expand.exe command refer to
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825253.aspx

The destination directory has to exist before executing the expand command. For example:

expand Dell-WinPE-Drivers-A02.CAB Dell-WinPE-Drivers-A02 -f:*