# editing pre-existing cab files/installer files

Tags: installation, download, windows-installer, cab

I'm currently trying to make a download/install file for a CD, and I've never done this or written any type of coding before so I'm somewhat at a loss. When we last created an installer package (I wasn't employed yet) we used InstalShield, but that was decades ago, and we can't afford the 500$+ price to get it again.

Currently I'm trying to work off the old download package we have. There is the Windows Installer Package (made by InstalShield) called CD Cat v6.msi, and then another file called CDcatv6.exe (which launches a window for the customer to browse options) and then a file called Data.cab which has all the files for the entire catalog in it.

I was thinking perhaps I can just replace a lot of those files with the current information. Replace the CDcatv6.exe file with my v7.exe file (but change the name so its CDcatv6.exe) and then replace all the files in the Data.cab file with the current ones. But that's turning out to be a huge issue.

I did a bit of searching to learn what a .cab file was, and downloaded the Cab File Maker 2.0 (after quite a bit of searching!). I'm having a difficult time using it though, as it wants all the files that I put in it to make the .cab to be in .ddf format. I have no idea what that is, much less how to make it. I tried using 'save as' to do it, but since all the files I need are PDF's there's no option for it and I cant export the files to it either.

I tried looking at other ways that people made Cab files, but I don't know many of the file types or programs their talking about. I'm not a programmer by any means, but I have to learn quick I guess, so any information on how to do this will help greatly. Is it even  possible to replace all the files seamlessly and have it work properly? Or is there an easier way to create a fill that the customer can click on and have it download to their desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think simple editing of Data.cab will work. There is installer logic stored in other InstallShield files. It could work if and only if the file set is the same, I mean no files changed its names, no new files added, no new registry entries required etc.

To create a CAB file, use [cabarc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx#top) from Microsoft Windows SDK.

---

Creating a brand new installer may be a better option. Look at this tools for creating installers:

- [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/)
- [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)
- [WiX toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) (with [tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/))

Comment: Ah I see, all those things considered it would be better to start fresh. Thanks for the links! I will certainly be checking those out.

Answer (score 2):

You best solution is to use **dark.exe** (part of the [WiX toolset](http://wix.sf.net)).

This will enable to you decompile the MSI and CAB files, edit the installer source as XML and then recompile this into a new executable. Unfortunately this route is not for the faint of heart and what you save on price will cost you in time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious how your company created an MSI decades ago, but Sasha is right about time and money trade-offs. However if you're working with Visual Studio, you might try the InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio. It may have enough capabilities to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing to `CABARC`, that looks exactly what i was looking for, due to information on:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb417343(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#top

That make me look how to download it, but i found this post:

[Where can I get the cabarc utility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361928/where-can-i-get-the-cabarc-utility)

Where it explains `CABARC` may be obsolete and there is another utility called `MAKECAB` that cames with Windows 11, i had try it at command line and it is there.

Thanks a lot.